# How to set input type month in order to increment/decrement automatically the year when cycling through the months?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am currently using this HTML input element on the chrome browser :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/month

I want to export a particular month of data from a year.

When I cycle through the months and reach January/December, I would like to decrement/increment the year when I am reaching January or December :

For instance, going from January 2020 to December 2019 and vice versa.

Currently, the element leaves the year as it is and the user must select the year then decrement/increment it (when using the two little arrow on the end of the field, not the little calendar pop-up) :

[input sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVGog.png)

I was thinking about doing that in JavaScript since the doc doesn't show any pieces of information about that.

But maybe there is a trick or something that I missed?

Thank you for your help, I hope my explanations are ok. :)

Comment: those controls are browser-specific ; some browser are lacking some kind of html5 inputs (color picker, month, etc.). Don't think you can use javascript for that. Maybe you should try a third-party calendar (will be available no matter which browser), such as https://docs.dhtmlx.com/suite/calendar__configuring.html#calendarmodes

Comment: To be fully honest I'm using AngularJS too, I was thinking about editing the value as soon as it changed, what do you think about that ? 
(I did not specified that I was using AngularJS in order to be a bit more generic).
But thanks, I could try that even if I'd like to avoid third-party stuff as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Pierre above (I couldn't set your comment as answer) :

> those controls are browser-specific ; some browser are lacking some kind of html5 >inputs (color picker, month, etc.). Don't think you can use javascript for that. Maybe >you should try a third-party calendar (will be available no matter which browser), such > as docs.dhtmlx.com/suite/calendar__configuring.html#calendarmodes

Thanks !